# SQL error: Invalid identifier

Tags: sql

I am an SQL rookie and I would very much appreciate some assistance on this rather basic issue.

```
select comp_table.*
from (select column_1,avg(column_2) as "avg"
      from table_1, group by column_1) comp_table
```

→ returns correct records with 2 columns named `column_1` and `avg`

But if I change to:

```
select comp_table.avg
from (select column_1,avg(column_2) as "avg"
      from table_1, group by column_1) comp_table
```

→ returns *Error: Invalid identifier "avg"*

The thing is I only need to select the `avg` column, so I cannot do `select comp_table.*`. Can you guys please help?

Also, if you could kindly provide some tuning tips for the query, that would be awesome.

Comment: Sounds like this is [ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the column name is not enclosed in "double quotes", the name is normalized to uppercase; therefore, you were asking for column "AVG", whereas the column name is actually "avg":

```
select comp_table."avg"
from (select column_1,avg(column_2) as "avg"
  from table_1, group by column_1) comp_table
```

Comment: in fact, I double-quote column identifiers only if I'd like to name them in my native language, otherwise I leave them "as is". It would also be a good practice not to use identifiers that match oracle function names like sum or avg, to avoid possible confusions.

Comment: In PostgreSQL enclose a columnname in double quote makes it case-sensitive, ie "mycolunm" differs from "myColumn". I don't know if it's the same for other databases.

Comment: In Oracle, it's a bit different. **ALL** columns are specified using double-quotes (in a sense) - it's just that they give us a short-cut that means we can omit the double-quotes if the column only includes uppercase letters and/or underscore characters. It's a common convention, however, to only use the non-quoted syntax for naming columns in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

What database server are you using?  `AVG` is a built-in function in all the ones I know of, so you would need to escape it correctly - which depends on database server.  In MS SQL Server it's `[avg]`

Comment: Then the error would've been that the AVG function is missing a parameter.  On top of the table alias use...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which DBMS you're using, but some will get upset that you are using `.avg` (because `avg` is reserved) and require you to escape it.

Try changing it from `avg` to `average`, just as a test:

```
SELECT comp_table.average
FROM (SELECT column_1, avg(column_2) as average
      FROM table_1, GROUP BY column_1) comp_table
```

Comment: Then the error would've been that the AVG function is missing a parameter.  On top of the table alias use...

Comment: TSQL is the only one I know of that supports square brackets to escape table, column and aliase names, which as Emtucifor pointed out--SQL Server wouldn't have this issue.